# How to reset progress on a mission?

Tags: destiny

I picked up a bounty now, where I have to kill the Divisive Mind in "The Black Garden" mission on Mars with the heroic modifier active.

So I pick that mission, level 20, which gives me the heroic modifier, and start it, ending up somewhere in the middle of the whole mission.

Probably I killed the Divisive Mind in this same bounty a while ago, and left to orbit, leaving the mission progress half-way.

If I pick it up at level 22, it starts back at the beginning, but if I then leave again and go back to level 20, it picks up in the middle again.

Is it possible to reset a mission, like this one at level 20, so that I start over at the beginning?

Note that I know that if I just continue the mission from where it currently starts, in the middle, and play it through to the end, getting the completion screen, then the next time it will start back at the beginning. My question is if there is another way to get it to start back at the beginning.

Comment: I would imagine things like restarting your console or starting some other mission would reset your progress in other missions? Maybe even logging out and in again? I've never met this problem myself, so I do not know what triggers this or not.

Comment: @Havatra restarting the console won't reset progress. I use the first mission on the moon to grind lots of Eris's bounties, and it always starts me at the same place even after powering off my console.

Comment: Last time I tried this It said it had to be a strike version of the mission and not just the mission. I got confused and dropped the bounty hah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply reset the progress of a mission by following this tip:

> **There is an option to resume or restart a mission when you hover over the emblem on the map.**

---

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70231136)

Answer (score 2):

Mission progress is stored for each partial completion at various checkmarks along the way. These checkmarks are stored on a per level basis, meaning that your progress will be different on different levels (if progress existed).

When hovering on an event with progress such as a raid or mission you will see the option to reset by pressing x. This will appear to be the same as selecting the mission with a, but once launch is selected, a confirmation box will appear ensuring you meant to reset.